# Mysql rows from table A with ID from query where ID matches one condition true in table B

Tags: mysql, join

```
    table wp_posts
    +-----+----------+
    | ID  |post_type |
    +-----+----------+
    |  1  |        A |
    |  2  |        A |
    |  3  |        A | 
    |  3  |        B | 
    |  3  |        C | 
    +-----+----------+
```

```
    table wp_term_relationships (object_id = wp_posts.ID)
    +-----------+------------------+
    | object_id | term_taxonomy_id |
    +-----------+------------------+
    |  1        |                1 |
    |  2        |                3 |
    |  2        |                2 |
    |  1        |                2 |
    |  3        |                1 | 
    +-----------+-------------------+
```

```
    table wp_esp_datetime (EVT_ID = wp_posts.ID)
    +-----------+---------------------+
    | EVT_ID    | DTT_EVT_end         |
    +-----------+---------------------+
    |  1        | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
    |  2        | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
    |  3        | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
    +-----------+---------------------+
```

Now what I want to do is:
query all from wp_posts with left joined datetime from wp_esp_datetime, but only those who have no entry in wp_term_relationships with term_taxonomy_id = 3.
My problem is, that the wp_post.ID can be multiple times in wp_term_relationships.object_id

**My current query looks like this:**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_esp_datetime on wp_posts.ID = wp_esp_datetime.EVT_ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'A' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

**So the question is:**

How can i exclude the row from wp_posts which has any entry with term_taxonomy_id = 3 in wp_term_relationships, even if there is a match with another term_taxonomy (not 3)?

Comment: Do you need wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id in your output, or don't you need that info as long as the query is correct?

Comment: I just need the ID from wp_posts and the DTT_EVT_end from wp_esp_datetime if the query is correct

Comment: ok, I have provided an answer that does that.

Comment: do you want all DTT_EVT_end dates or just one per wp_post.ID, and if so, should it be the max or the min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an (not) exists clause

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on p.ID = tr.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_esp_datetime ed on p.ID = ed.EVT_ID 
WHERE p.post_type = 'A' 
and not exists (select null 
                from wp_term_relationships
                where term_taxonomy_id = 3
                and p.ID = object_id)
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Using NOT EXISTS or NOT IN like from Mateo is causing me a syntax error and it seems I'm either to stupid, or this aint working.

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id LEFT JOIN wp_esp_datetime on wp_posts.ID = wp_esp_datetime.EVT_ID WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'A' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 3 and wp_posts.ID = object_id ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID`

Comment: How strange... You tried the query itself on a shell ?

Comment: @m.b See the usage of aliases in my query, and look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/519b9d/1

Comment: my god, thx a lot guys! I tried to run this via phpMyAdmin -> Syntax error. But it is running fine within my php script.

Comment: While performant, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate in this context (just as it is in the original query), and has the potential to produce erroneous or misleading results.

Comment: But how else do I make sure, I only get each p.ID once?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a subquery ?

```
 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN
(SELECT wtr2.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships wtr2 WHERE wtr2.term_taxonomy_id = 3)
```

Your query edited :

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr on p.ID = wtr.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_esp_datetime wed on p.ID = wed.EVT_ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'A'
AND p.ID NOT IN (SELECT wtr2.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships wtr2 WHERE wtr2.term_taxonomy_id = 3)
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: `NOT IN (*subquery*)` can be slow as hell, `EXISTS` should be used.

Comment: Sure you're right, but I think in this case it won't change anything (or almost), and it's quite more readable / understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` and remove the join with **wp_term_relationships**:

```
SELECT      p.ID, ed.DTT_EVT_end 
FROM        wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN   wp_esp_datetime ed on p.ID = ed.EVT_ID 
WHERE       p.post_type = 'A' 
AND         NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  1 
                FROM    wp_term_relationships
                WHERE   term_taxonomy_id = 3
                AND     p.ID = object_id)
ORDER BY    p.ID, ed.DTT_EVT_end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what part of the problem the following fails to address...

```
SELECT p.*
     , d.*
  FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_esp_datetime d 
    ON d.evt_id = p.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_term_relationships r
    ON r.object_id = p.id 
   AND r.term_taxonomy_id = 3
 WHERE term_taxonomy_id IS NULL;
```

This will produce the following result...

```
 +----+-----------+--------+---------------------+
 | ID | post_type | EVT_ID | DTT_EVT_end         |
 +----+-----------+--------+---------------------+
 |  1 | A         |      1 | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
 |  3 | A         |      3 | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
 |  3 | B         |      3 | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
 |  3 | C         |      3 | 2015-12-01 16:00:00 |
 +----+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

It would seem nonsensical to apply a GROUP BY clause to this result set.